# Sybase bcp data type date and text to oracle database using sqlldr

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to migrate a table from sybase database to Oracle database.
Following is the structure of my sybase database.

[image]

I have used bcp to extract all records. My extracted records as below -

```
1|0.1|1/7/2010 12:00:00 AM|<exm><id>1</id></exm> 
2|0.2|1/8/2010 12:00:00 AM|<exm><id>1</id></exm>
```

I am using following sqlldr command to insert records into oracle database.

```
sqlldr \'username/passwd@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost.com)(PORT=1111)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MYSIDE)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))\' control=loader.ctl log=mylog.log
```

This is my loader file(loader.ctl)

```
LOAD DATA 
INLINE '/tmp/bcp_out.txt'
INTO TABLE MY_TABLE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(ID,
VERSION,
DATE,
STATEMENT CHAR(10000))
```

Table created in Oracle -
[image]

So from the above table, we want the date coming from sybase to be converted to oracle timestamp and statement to be converted as Oracle CLOB.

Could you please suggest what changes I have to make in loader file to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target table (in Oracle; note that `date` is an invalid column name (unless enclosed into double quotes, but I wouldn't recommend that)):

```
SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 VERSION                                            VARCHAR2(5)
 DATUM                                              TIMESTAMP(6)
 STATEMENT                                          CLOB

SQL>
```

Control file (sample data included; you'll probably have it in a separate file; also, I don't know what 1/7/2010 really represents - is it 1st of July or 7th of January - date format might need to be changed):

```
load data 
infile *
replace
into table test
fields terminated by '|'
trailing nullcols
( 
id,
version,
datum "to_date(:datum, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss am')",
statement
)

begindata
1|0.1|1/7/2010 12:00:00 AM|<exm><id>1</id></exm> 
2|0.2|1/8/2010 12:00:00 AM|<exm><id>1</id></exm>
```

Loading session and the result:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger control=test22.ctl log=test22.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Uto Lis 13 18:16:41 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 1
Commit point reached - logical record count 2
    
SQL> -- you don't have to do that; I'm just showing *what is what* in the timestamp
SQL> alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mi:ss.ff6';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID VERSION DATUM                          STATEMENT
---------- ------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
         1 0.1     01.07.2010 12:00:00.000000 AM  <exm><id>1</id></exm>
         2 0.2     01.08.2010 12:00:00.000000 AM  <exm><id>1</id></exm>


SQL>
```

---

As of another date format:

```
SQL> select to_timestamp('1 Mon 2020 12:00:00:000 am', 'dd Mon yyyy hh:mi:ss:ff am') from dual;

TO_TIMESTAMP('1SIJ202012:00:00:000AM','DDMONYYYYHH:MI:SS:FFAM')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
01.01.20 00:00:00,000000000

SQL>
```

Comment: I have created the control file as yours but getting following error on log file - 
ORA-01950: no privileges on table space ''PORTDATA'

Comment: DBA has to grant you quota on that tablespace,

Comment: Sorry about that .. That's got sorted. Also I am interested to know what should be the date format if the date coming as - Jan  1 2010 12:00:00:000AM

Comment: You'd use appropriate format mask: `dd Mon yyyy hh:mi:ss:ff am`

Comment: It's saying date format not recognized. Tried MMM instead of Mon and getting same error. Is  there any other aspect I can look at?

Comment: Ah, sorry; month comes first, day next so: `Mon dd yyyy hh:mi:ss:ff am`

Comment: I posted an example (at the bottom of the answer) which shows that - if you use correct format mask - it *works*.

Comment: On thing I noticed that in my bcp out there is a extra space in between month and date i.e Jan  1 2020  12:00:00:000AM. Is there any way I can format it ?

Comment: It doesn't matter (the space, I mean).

Comment: Thyanks man. It really helped. It worked for me :) I will accept this answer

Comment: Could you please throw some light on this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64337829/sybase-bcp-out-single-row-extract-coming-as-multi-line

Comment: Sorry, I don't know bcp; no idea why you got such an output.

Comment: No worries. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the oracle data type to be TIMESTAMP?  From what I see DATE would be sufficient. In oracle, unlike some other rdbms, a datatype of DATE *includes* time, down to the second.  In oracle TIMESTAMP includes date and time down to the nano-second and can also have timezone variants.

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-control-file-contents.html#GUID-5740B2F9-C5C3-4D44-BB3F-81484417F02D) gives a very good example of dealing with dates in your input csv file. Adapting that to your situation:

```
LOAD DATA 
INLINE '/tmp/bcp_out.txt'
INTO TABLE MY_TABLE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
DATE FORMAT "mm/dd/yyyy hh12:mi:ss AM"
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(ID,
VERSION,
DATE,
STATEMENT CHAR(10000))
```

Further explanations of the date format model [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212).

As for the clob, I can't help there. Never done it myself, but I'd start by looking at the docs for sqlldr.